# How to do clustering using the matrix of correlation coefficients?

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, correlation, linkage

I have a correlation coefficient matrix (n*n). How to do clustering using the correlation coefficient matrix?

Can I use linkage and fcluster function in SciPy?

Linkage function needs `n * m` matrix (according to tutorial), but I want to use n*n matrix.

My code is

```
corre = mp_N.corr()    # mp_N is raw data (m*n matrix)  
Z = linkage(corre, method='average')  # 'corre' is correlation coefficient matrix
fcluster(Z,2,'distance')
```

Is this code right?
If this code is wrong, how can I do clustering with correlation coefficient matrix?

Comment: With out example data, expected results and returned results, no one can tell if your code is right.  Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Additionally, you may find some more clustering libraries and examples in the [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) package.

Answer (score 13):

Clustering data using a correlation matrix is a reasonable idea, but one has to pre-process the correlations first. First, the correlation matrix, as returned by `numpy.corrcoef`, is affected by the errors of machine arithmetics:

1. It is not always symmetric.
2. Diagonal terms are not always exactly 1

These can be fixed by taking average with the transpose, and filling the diagonal with 1:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(20, 10))   # 20 variables with 10 observations each
corr = np.corrcoef(data)                         # 20 by 20 correlation matrix
corr = (corr + corr.T)/2                         # made symmetric
np.fill_diagonal(corr, 1)                        # put 1 on the diagonal
```

Second, the input to any clustering method, such as `linkage`, needs to measure the **dissimilarity** of objects. The correlation measures **similarity**. So it needs to be transformed in a way such that 0 correlation is mapped to a large number, while 1 correlation is mapped to 0.

[This blog post](http://research.stowers.org/mcm/efg/R/Visualization/cor-cluster/index.htm) discusses several ways of such data transformation, and recommends `dissimilarity = 1 - abs(correlation)`. The idea is that strong negative correlation is also an indication that the objects are related, just as positive correlation is. Here is the continuation of the example:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, fcluster
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

dissimilarity = 1 - np.abs(corr)
hierarchy = linkage(squareform(dissimilarity), method='average')
labels = fcluster(hierarchy, 0.5, criterion='distance')
```

Note that we don't feed a full distance matrix into `linkage`, it needs to be compressed with `squareform` first.

What exact clustering methods to use, and what thresholds, depends on the context of your problem, there are no universal rules. Often, 0.5 is a reasonable threshold to use for correlation, so I did that. With my 20 sets of random numbers I ended up with 7 clusters: encoded in `labels` as

```
[7, 7, 7, 1, 4, 4, 2, 7, 5, 7, 2, 5, 6, 3, 6, 1, 5, 1, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Nice answer! Your mentioning of distance (dissimilarity) and correlation (similarity) is essential to me.

Comment: `squareform()` is the key to convert between the dense matrix form and condensed vector form of correlation. And in terms of making correlation a _distance_, let me add that scipy uses `1 - corr`, which has a different consideration as `1 - abs(corr)`. I am not sure which one to use so I decided to follow the way of scipy.

Comment: Your link to the blog post is outdated.

Comment: I'd recommend `squareform(corr, checks=False, force='tovector')` to not check the diagonal elements (since they are discarded) and force the direction of conversion.

Comment: What does one do with `labels` to then order and plot the correlation matrix?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer you could try `matrix[labels, :][:, lables]` assuming your labels are sorted