# Assigning cluster values based on correlation matrix

Tags: python, iteration, cluster-analysis, correlation

I have a n*n correlation matrix in python dataframe. I want to assign cluster value based on this matrix, say( a correlation>0.08) goes into one cluster and so on:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
# ==============================
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))

df1=df.corr()

    A               B              C              D             E
A   1              -0.052234579    -0.098678285   0.063338014   -0.097187103
B   -0.052234579    1              -0.015077115   0.058672786   0.140833111
C   -0.098678285   -0.105077115     1             0.008695575   0.048329744
D   0.063338014     0.058672786     0.008695575   1             0.120529455
E   -0.097187103    0.140833111     0.048329744   0.120529455   1

d={}
i=1
while df1.shape[0]>0:
     x=(abs(df1.head(1))>0.08).T
     x1=list(x[x[x.columns[0]]==True].index)
     d[i]=x1
     df1=df1[~df1.index.isin(x1)][list(df1.columns-x1)]
     i+=1
d>>
{1: ['A', 'C', 'E'], 2: ['B'], 3: ['D']}
```

Now my challenge here is, say a variable has correlation value>0.08, but has stronger correlation with another variable which is not in current cluster, then ideally it should be in different cluster.

e.g. 'E' has correlation of -0.09 with A so it is in cluster 1, but it has stronger correl(0.14) with B, so ideally, it should be in cluster 2.
so Ideal cluster assignment would have been:

```
{1: ['A', 'C'], 2: ['B','D','E']}
```

How can i address this iterative problem?

Comment: why the down vote? I have put forward all the facts (

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute correlations, and then use **hierarchical agglomerative clustering**.

Every point is it's own cluster. You then merge those two with the **best** correlation. If the correlation is too weak, then you stop merging.

Comment: I tried that, but it's not giving expected results. even variables with low correlation are ending up in same cluster, which defeats the purpose

Comment: Probably because the function you call expects a distance but you provide a similarity matrix?

Comment: i used dissimilarity as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070478/how-to-do-clustering-using-the-matrix-of-correlation-coefficients

Comment: Maybe the code you copy&pasted did not work? Also make sure to understand if you want single linkage, complete linkage, etc.